# d3v4 - zooming (Equivalent to d3.zoom.x)

Tags: javascript, zooming, d3.js

I'm migrating my d3 code from v3 to v4 and having issues finding an equivalent for the d3.zoom.x, d3.zoom.y properties.

Here's a short part of the code, including the most important elements:

```
            this.init = function(obj, def) {

            /* X-axis */
            x = d3.scaleTime()
                .range([0, width]);


            xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                .ticks(ticks);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

            /* Y-axis */
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                // Returns the y and yAxis as arrays
                createYAxis(i);
            }

            initZoom();

        };
            // Zoom trigger
            var drawUpdXY = function(){
                setPause(true);
                drawUpd();
                zoomY.y(y[0]);
                zoomX.x(x);


            zoom = d3.zoom()
                .on("zoom", drawUpdXY);

            zoomX = d3.zoom()
                .on("zoom", drawUpdX);

            zoomY = d3.zoom()
                .on("zoom", drawUpdY);
            };
```

I've tried to use this to replace "zoom.x(x); zoom.y(y[0])"

```
      xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x));
      yAxis[0].scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y[0]));
```

However, these only rescale the axis, leaving the data non-zommed.

Comment: Since this is rather old, did you ever find a solution? I am stuck on the same problem.

Comment: Haven't found a solution to this day - I decided to wait until there's a bigger community for v4.

Comment: **_tl;dr:_ It might help to restructure your refactor, see the links for a walk through of why and how, and an example of it working** I'm working on a similar project trying to implement a panning/zooming coordinate grid system in d3v4 and React. Along the way, I used this [article explaining how the new zooming/panning works](http://emptypipes.org/2016/07/03/d3-panning-and-zooming/), and made me realize I had to rethink how I structured my refactor. Then, I created this [codepen of what I was trying to make](https://codepen.io/mduleone/pen/wJxrbj) in pure d3. Still working on the React side.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to how d3 v3 handled zoom, since I've only recently started working with D3, but the code below should get you pointed in the right direction. I'll do my best to describe what's going. I invite corrections, improvements, and better explanations.

First, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Energy Visualizer</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #4e5965;
    }
  </style>
  </svg>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart" />
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var data = [{
      "x": 2,
      "y": 8,
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 6,
      "color": "red"
    }];

    var width = svg.attr("width");
    var height = svg.attr("height");

    x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, width]);
    y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, height]);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x_scale(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y_scale(d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color
      });

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x_scale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y_scale);

    var x_axis = svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
    var y_axis = svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is just a simple scatter plot with a red and green circle. You can see how I've broken out the components of the x and y axis. This comes into play with `d3.zoom()`.

Next, let's add a zoom component.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Energy Visualizer</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #4e5965;
    }
  </style>
  </svg>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart" />
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom);

    var data = [{
      "x": 2,
      "y": 8,
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 6,
      "color": "red"
    }];

    var width = svg.attr("width");
    var height = svg.attr("height");

    x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, width]);
    y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, height]);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x_scale(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y_scale(d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color
      });

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x_scale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y_scale);

    var x_axis = svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
    var y_axis = svg.append("g").call(yAxis);


    function zoomed() {
      var new_x_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_scale);
      var new_y_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y_scale);

      x_axis.transition()
        .duration(0)
        .call(xAxis.scale(new_x_scale));

      y_axis.transition()
        .duration(0)
        .call(yAxis.scale(new_y_scale));

      circles
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return new_x_scale(d.x)
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return new_y_scale(d.y)
        });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, you can see that chart allows zoom-in, zoom-out and dragging across both axes. I beleive you are wanting only a single axis zoom, so in that case, only rescale the x-axis and the x component of each circles position.

One last snippet doing what I think you want.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Energy Visualizer</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #4e5965;
    }
  </style>
  </svg>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart" />
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom);

    var data = [{
      "x": 2,
      "y": 8,
      "color": "green"
    }, {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 6,
      "color": "red"
    }];

    var width = svg.attr("width");
    var height = svg.attr("height");

    x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, width]);
    y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, height]);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x_scale(d.x);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y_scale(d.y);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color
      });

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x_scale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y_scale);

    var x_axis = svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
    var y_axis = svg.append("g").call(yAxis);


    function zoomed() {
      var new_x_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_scale);

      x_axis.transition()
        .duration(0)
        .call(xAxis.scale(new_x_scale));

      circles
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return new_x_scale(d.x)
        });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```